# How do i get a "Web Application Interface"-based Server run with HTTPS?

Tags: haskell

I'm experimenting with WAI and couldn't find a Setting or Middleware to allow access via HTTPS. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the warp-tls package.